# How to trigger a specific job in gitlab

Tags: post, tags, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to run a specific job in a pipeline , I thought assigning a tag for the job and then specifying this tag again in the post method will fulfill my needs .The problem is when I trigger using the api(post) , all the jobs in the pipeline are triggered event though only one of this tagged .

gitlab-ci.yml :

job1:
  script:
    - echo "helloworld!"
  tags : [myTag]

job2:
  script:
    - echo "hello gitlab!"

---

the api call :
curl -X POST -F token="xxx" -F ref="myTag" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/trigger/pipeline

Answer (score 15):

add a variable to your trigger api call as shown here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables

then use the `only` prperty 
inside your `gitlab.yml` file
as shown here :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#environment-variables-expressions

then **only if the variable exists the job will be execute**

for example

```
job1:
  script: echo "HELLO"
  only:
    variables:
      - $variables[API_CALL]=true
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but what  exactly am looking for is choosing the job from the api (passing it as a parameter).

Comment: This is as far as I know not possible.

Comment: Should it be
```only:
    variables:
      - API_CALL == "true"
```

as per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#environment-variables-expressions

Comment: Depend on your gitlab version the answer is almost one year old

Comment: Hey how can i define mutable variables for the curl request?

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that all other jobs in your CI script will still be triggered. You'll need to add `rules` for every job in your CI script to handle this if you want those jobs to run only on things like `push` events.

Answer (score 14):

Probably changes in GitLab makes answers above not working.
The

```
only:
  variables:
    - $variables[....]
```

syntax trigger CI Lint.

[image]

For others that come here like me, here's how I trigger a specific job:

```
job1:
  script: 
    - echo "HELLO for job1"
    - "curl 
      --request POST
      --form token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN
      --form ref=master
      --form variables[TRIGGER_JOB]=job2
      https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline"
  except:
    - pipelines

job2:
  script: echo "HELLO for job2"
  only:
    variables:
      - $TRIGGER_JOB == "job2"
```

## ⚠️ Note the `except - pipelines` in job1, else, you go in infinite Child pipeline loop!

[image: trigger a specific job]

Answer (score 7):

By using variables you can do:

Use this curl command to trigger the pipeline with a variable

```
curl --request POST --form token=${TOKEN} --form ref=master --form "variables[TRIGERRED_JOB]=job1" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline"
```

Ofcourse you have to set the variable accordingly.

Define your jobs with the appropriate variable:

```
job1:
  script: echo "HELLO for job1"
  only:
    variables:
      - $variables[TRIGERRED_JOB] == "JOB1"

job2:
  script: echo "HELLO for job2"
  only:
    variables:
      - $variables[TRIGERRED_JOB] == "JOB2"
```

> if you are running the curl from inside another/same job you can use ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} instead of $TOKEN and

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables