# Gitlab run job either by trigger or changes

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am trying to trigger a **particular job** in CI after either of the 2 conditions

1. trigger by another job in the same pipeline 
   OR
2. changes: somefile.txt

My CI is as described

```
job1:
    stage: build
    script: 
    - echo "JOb1"
    - curl -X POST -F token=2342344444 -F "variables[TRIGGER_JOB]=job1" -F ref=master https://main.gitlab.myconmpanyxyz.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline
    only:
     changes:
     - job1.md

job2: # This does not RUN as expected because of the TRIGGER_JOB set to job1
    stage: test
    script: 
    - echo "Job2"   
    rules:
    - if: $TRIGGER_JOB =="job2"

job3: # this RUNS as expected because of VARIABLE TRIGGER_JOB
    stage: test
    script: 
    - echo "Job3"   
    rules:
    - if: $TRIGGER_JOB =="job1"

job4: # this also RUNS, but this should not be the expected behavior 
    stage: test
    script: 
    - echo “job4“   
    rules:
    - if: $TRIGGER_JOB == "xyz"
    - changes: 
      - job4.md
```

After job1 finishes it also needs to call job4 and **not any other jobs** (job2 in this case). So I am using CURL to call the job itself. If there are any better ways of calling a specific job in the same CI, also please let me know.
I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56699829/how-to-trigger-a-specific-job-in-gitlab) stack-overflow page, but it does not help because my job needs to be triggered by either of **2 conditions** which is not allowed bit gitlab-ci.

I need job4 to be called by either of the 2 conditions - if the **TRIGGER_JOB=="job1"** or if there are any **changes in job4.md** file. 
Currently job4 runs if changes are made in job4.md file, however it also runs if the job1 is triggered. But afaik this should not be the expected behavior. 
[docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges). Can anyone please give me some leads how to create this kind of design.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was almost correct, but the `changes` keyword with `only` or `except` does only work, if the pipeline is triggered by a `push` or a `merge_request` event. This is defined in the variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`. When you trigger the pipeline by calling the API, the variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` contains the value `trigger` and therefore `only:changes` returns always true, which triggers `job1` again and ends in an endless loop. You can add a simple `except` rule to your `job1` to prevent that:

```
job1:
    stage: build
    script: 
    - echo "JOb1"
    - curl -X POST -F token=2342344444 -F "variables[TRIGGER_JOB]=job1" -F ref=master https://main.gitlab.myconmpanyxyz.com/api/v4/projects/1234/trigger/pipeline
    only:
     changes:
       - job1.md
    except:
      variables:
        - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
```

You can find more information on `only/except:changes` in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges).